# Azure - How to programmatically distinguish between different events (deployment vs restart vs VM move)

Tags: azure, azure-web-roles, azure-powershell, paas

In Azure Web Role (PaaS model), is there a way to programmatically distinguish between a regular deployment vs Reboot/Restart vs VM move event

I need to run certain startup tasks, or certain conditional code based on whether we are deploying code, or whether Azure Instances were rebooted, or when a VM has been moved internally by Azure and the C: drive got wiped. Something like:

```
if(deployment) do x
 else if(restart) do y
 else if (VM has moved) do z
```

Comment: I believe the answer is no, but I might be wrong, I haven't worked with those extensively.

Comment: whenever a web or worker role gets stopped/ rebooted / recycled the OnStop() event in the webrole/workerrole class. you can do some custom logging there . But again I don't think you can capture the cause of reboot. You can try remoting to that VM, enable tracing there and then use debugview tool to look through the logs.

Comment: We went to Microsoft with this question, and the response was that we cannot detect life cycle events via startup tasks or through their api. A workaround that was suggested was to create a temporary file a.k.a "bread crumb" and play with it to achieve the desired result (different combinations of restart, patching, E/F drive replacements, VM moves etc.)